# Bathroom shower remodel old mortar stuck to concrete walls

Tags: shower, removal, mortar

I have removed the old tile in my shower to install new tile. The mortar is stuck on and very hard to remove. Can I smooth it out with joint compound and make a smooth as possible surface and tile over that? They don’t sell thin set here in Costa Rica. Only mortar.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use joint compound. If water gets to it it will soften.

Grind off as much of the old mortar as you can and skim with new thin set. Then use a [waterproofing paint](https://www.lowes.com/pd/MAPEI-Mapelastic-Aquadefense-3-5-Gallon-Liquid-Membrane/5013794419?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-flr-_-ggl-_-LIA_FLR_244_Tools-Setting-Materials-Access-_-5013794419-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjw5MOlBhBTEiwAAJ8e1o_m16kDjGzuc3C_CNutOtMDJG7Fewlr5a7020JSb1q5ecuTMbUrNxoCkasQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) that is available in your location.

Comment: Grind or chip.... I'd consider reaching for a cold chisel first

Comment: Unless I was skint, if my wall had old mortar adhering to it in any great quantity, I'd probably simply replace the backing (assumed to be CBU) for a fresh surface.

Comment: @Huesmann you may want to define "CBU". OP is in Costa Rica, but I'm not sure what that is, either...

Comment: Cementitious Backer Unit, i.e. cement board.